# Hide button content with text

Tags: jquery, wordpress, elementor

I'm looking for the jquery code that allows me to place "call" or "show number" on my elementor button because I need to hide the number.

[image]

like houzez does

[image]

[Source page](https://demo01.houzez.co/agent/brittany-watkins/)

I already have an old code that allows me to display a section and delete the button.. not very practical as an idea ..

I need to understand how to adapt it to just hide the number with text
I'm not comfortable with jquery there must be a better tip.

```
/*Remove Button After Show*/    
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#MY_BTN").click(function(){ 
  $('#hide_content').slideToggle('250','swing','hide');
  this.remove();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of ways to do it. I would do something simple like the following.

When clicking the button, the text will be changed to what is in the `data-text` attribute.

HTML:

```
<button data-text="123 345 565" class="phone-reveal">Call</button>
```

JS:

```
$('.phone-reveal').on('click', function() {
  $(this).innerText = $(this).data('text');
});
```

Comment: I can't get it to work
I am with the latest wordpress 5.8 and elementor free version
clean install 0 plugin or modification
[it seems something does not support the code](https://ibb.co/CWRR4by)
can you test with me in real conditions with elementor? and confirm that it works?
[I'm using the html widget](https://elementor.com/help/html-widget/)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with wordpress. Try

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$('.phone-reveal').on('click', function() {
  $(this).innerText = $(this).data('text');
});
});

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. tested with jquery version 3.6.
When click on button the number will show.

```
  <button data-number="123 345 565" class="phone-reveal">Call</button>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $('.phone-reveal').on('click', function () {
                let phone = jQuery(this).data('number')
                jQuery(this).text(phone)
            });
        })
        
    </script>
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the code
I can't get it to work
I am with the latest wordpress 5.8 and elementor free version
clean install 0 plugin or modification
[it seems something does not support the code](https://ibb.co/CWRR4by)
can you test with me in real conditions with elementor? and confirm that it works?
[I'm using the html widget](https://elementor.com/help/html-widget/)